# IllegalStateException with postgresql driver

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, illegalstateexception

I have this in my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://1.2.3.4:5432/myapp?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory&sslmode=require
spring.datasource.username=account
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=10
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=10
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=100
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=100
```

When I atempt to run my application it fails to start with:

> Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.postgresql.Driver

I tried adding a local postgresql jar to the dependencies in IntelliJ but this made no difference. I also included `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` in my pom.xml. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

What is the dependency which you've added?
If you are using `spring-boot-parent` and it's dependencies then it's enough to include this one

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Did you also refreshed the project inside intellij (maven or gradle or what are you using) when you've added that dependency?